# Find the number of permutation in $S_6$ which are conjugate to $\sigma$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

The number of permutation in $S_6$ which are conjugate to $\sigma$, where $\sigma=(1 2) (3 4)$ is equal to $a) \ 15\ b)\ 30\ c)\ 45\ d)\ 60$

Comment: the key result is that two permutations are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle type.

Answer (score 2):

Hint :- A permutation $\phi$ is conjugate to $\sigma$ iff $\phi$ and $\sigma$ have the same cycle type. $\sigma$ has the cycle type $(a,b)(c,d)$.

So can you calculate the total number of ways in which you can write $(a,b)(c,d)$ where $a,b,c,d$ are to chosen from 6 characters ?

Answer (score 0):

A general result would help you to solve the problem.

> Let $\alpha\in S_n$ be written as a product of disjoint permutations which consists of $e_1$ cycles of length $1$, $e_2$ cycles of length $2$,$\dots$, $e_n$ cycles of length $n$, then the size of its conjugacy class is $$\frac{n!}{1^{e_1}e_1!2^{e_n}2!\dots n^{e_n}n!}$$

For your question,since $\sigma$ is written as $2$ cycles of length $1$, and $2$ cycles of length $2$, the answer should be $$\frac{6!}{1^22!2^22!}=45$$

Comment: uff!!! nice...thanks a lot